# Amazon MWS Product Feed Not Submitting

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am working on the Amazon API. I want to submit the product feed on amazon account.

I have validated the XML file (product feed) by the Amazon Scratch Pad and i get the Response that Feed is submitted but when i run the script, to submit the same feed by script, i don't get any response.

Here is my code :

```
$req = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest();
$req->setMerchant(MERCHANTID);
$req->setMarketplaceIdList(MARKETPLACEID);
$req->setFeedType('_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_');
$req->setContentMd5(base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($fh), true)));
rewind($fh);
$req->setPurgeAndReplace(true);
$req->setFeedContent($fh);
$res = $mws->submitFeed($request);
echo $res;
```

I am unable to get the response, when i echo the `$res`.

---

I have changed the  `$res = $mws->submitFeed($request);` to `$res = $mws->submitFeed($req);`. Still no success in submitting the feed. I am not getting any response header that Amazon return while submitting the feed.

The code is like this :

```
$req = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest();
$fh = fopen('feed.xml', 'r');
$req->setMerchant(MERCHANTID);
$req->setMarketplaceIdList(MARKETPLACEID);
$req->setFeedType('_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_');
$req->setContentMd5(base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($fh), true)));
rewind($fh);
$req->setPurgeAndReplace(true);
$req->setFeedContent($fh);
$res = $mws->submitFeed($req);
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other things that might go wrong: You are submitting `$request`, while the thing you probably want to submit is `$req`.

Edit: Since you corrected this mistake but still have no result...:

`submitFeed()` returns a `MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedResponse` object.

Echo does not work with objects, unless the object has a `__toString()` method, which this class doesn't. Try using `print_r($res)` or `var_dump($res)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array($MARKETPLACE_ID));
     $feedHandle = @fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
     fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
     rewind($feedHandle); 

     $parameters = array(
         'Merchant' => $MERCHANT_ID,
         'MarketplaceIdList' => $marketplaceIdArray,
         'FeedType' => '_POST_PRODUCT_DATA_',
         'FeedContent' => $feedHandle,
         'PurgeAndReplace' => false, 
         'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true))
     );

     rewind($feedHandle);
     $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_SubmitFeedRequest($parameters);

     $return_feed = invokeSubmitFeed($service, $request);

     fclose($feedHandle);
```